# In Android i want to set a loop for button events

Tags: android

I have created a one app in android in which i have one button and i want that the button should be clicked only 4 time. so which type of codes required? After clicking button 4 times this button should not give any type of response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`package com.example.test;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private int buttonClick;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        buttonClick = 0;
        final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.mybutton);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                buttonClick++;
                if(buttonClick < 5){
                    // Do some processing
                }
                else {
                    button.setEnabled(false);
                }
            }
        });
    }

}`

Answer (score 3):

this is basic stuff, just use a counter and an if statement

Answer (score 1):

You can use a counter and wrap your button's onClick logic in a if/else statement.

Answer (score 1):

Set a class int like `private static mNumberTimesClicked` and then in your onClick handler put

```
if (mNumberTimesClicked <= 4) {
    mNumberTimesClicked++;
    /* Do Stuff./ */
}
```